# how to add values to JSON array without full path?

Tags: json, jq

I have a problem with 'jq' I could not solve after searching for a few hours. Let's take this simple JSON as an example with "Category4" nested within "Category2":

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Category1",
      "Children": []
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Category2",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Category4",
          "Children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Category3",
      "Children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add a "Category5" child within the "Category4" object such as:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Category1",
      "Children": []
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Category2",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Category4",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Id": 5,
              "Name": "Category5",
              "Children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Category3",
      "Children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I can do it by using the full path of the "Category4" object with:

```
jq --argjson a '[{"Id":5,"Name":"Category5","Children":[]}]' '.categories[1].Children[0].Children += $a' "myfile.json"
```

But how can I achieve the same result if I don't know the position of "Category4" (which could be at root level or nested deep inside other objects)? This command was my best guess:

```
jq --argjson a '[{"Id":5,"Name":"Category5","Children":[]}]' '.. | select(.Id?==4) | .Children += $a' "myfile"
```

but it only retrieves "Category4" and "Category5" objects (Category1, 2 and 3 are missing from the output). I feel like I am missing something stupid...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`walk` builtin](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/?#walk(f)) for applying filters to values at arbitrary depths without changing the overall structure.

```
walk(select(.Id? == 4) .Children += $a)
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/tjsiMN9BcD)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!!! I have a question though, "walk" re-orders the objects: Category 5 and 4 are displayed before Category2 (which bothers me if I flatten the tree). Is there a way to keep the original order of objects? Note I am using jq 1.5 so I had to define "walk" manually as explained on https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/963 (I don't know if it makes a difference)

Comment: @max It doesn't reorder anything. Better upgrade to 1.6 because I don't have JQ 1.5 on my machine so even if I had idea I wouldn't be able to test it.

Comment: Thank you so much again! I just tried with the 1.6 binary (with built-in "walk" function) and I confirm this one does NOT reorder. So everything is fine

Comment: If your `walk` is reordering keys, it’s because its def uses `keys` instead of `keys_unsorted`. So you could simply change `reduce keys[] ...` to `reduce keys_unsorted[] ...`